# VideoView in ScrollView not working in AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, scrollview, android-videoview

I'm using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), and I would like to have a **VideoView** in the sliding layout. 
So, in the code, I'm using the following lines to define the drag area (to collapse and expand the sliding layout):

```
    SlidingUpPanelLayout layout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout)
    findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout); 
    layout.setDragView(findViewById(R.id.main_title_bar));
    layout.setEnableDragViewTouchEvents(true);
```

and the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".VideoMapPanel" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
        sothree:paralaxOffset="100dp"
        sothree:dragView="@+id/dragView"
        >

        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <FrameLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                sothree:theme="@style/ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Main Content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:textSize="16sp" />



                <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#eeeeee"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:id="@+id/dragView">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:id="@+id/main_title_bar"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

                       <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </ProgressBar> 

                  <ImageView
                     android:id="@+id/tvLogo"
                     android:layout_width="50dip"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:paddingRight="10dp"
                     android:gravity="center_vertical" />

            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/menuLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">



                                  <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/fbLogo"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="0.8"
                     android:src="@drawable/facebook_logo"
                     />


                         <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/twitterLogo"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="0.8"
                     android:src="@drawable/twitter_logo"
                     />



                                             <ImageButton
                     android:id="@+id/webLogo"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     android:layout_weight="0.8"
                     android:src="@drawable/web_logo"
                     />    



             </LinearLayout>   


<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


            <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionLayout"
   android:layout_gravity="center" >


                        <com.myapp.ex.ExpandableTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDescription"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"/>


     <VideoView

        android:id="@+id/liveView"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

  </RelativeLayout>    

    </ScrollView>     

 </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The issue is that **ScrollView** is not working when I try to scroll the content, and the Video is not show in the VideoView.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478361/slidinguppanellayout-and-scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Solved, temporary, avoiding putting VideoView in ScrollView.
This seems to be a VideoView bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37229