# ScrollView in SlidingUpPanel Never works

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview

I have tried everything to get my `ScrollView` and `SlidingUpPanelLayout` to function how Google Maps app handles it. ([video example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MUsmQzusX8&feature=youtu.be))

This is the only link that seems to actually be working for people, but it is not working for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720204/172336

I've followed it 4 times today and every time my `ScrollView` scrolls and my `SlidingUpPanelLayout` does absolutely nothing. (It sits there)

Here is the code I am adding to the code from the `SlidingUpPanelLayout` as seen on GitHub.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.bouy76.sportsmantracker.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:panelHeight="68dp"
    app:dragView="@+id/drag_view"

    app:scrollView="@+id/scroll_view"> <!-- attrs.xml tag -->

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top">

        <com.nutiteq.MapView
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drag_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="68dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="Near Beaver Creek"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView

            android:id="@+id/scroll_view" <!-- Match attrs reference -->

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="5000dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.bouy76.sportsmantracker.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

**SlidingUpPanelLayout.java**

```
View mScrollView;
int mScrollViewResId = -1;
boolean isChildHandlingTouch = false;
float mPrevMotionX;
float mPrevMotionY;

...

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    if (mDragViewResId != -1) {
        setDragView(findViewById(mDragViewResId));
    }
    if (mScrollViewResId != -1) {
        mScrollView = findViewById(mScrollViewResId);
    }
}

...

private boolean isScrollViewUnder(int x, int y) {
if (mScrollView == null)
    return false;

int[] viewLocation = new int[2];
mScrollView.getLocationOnScreen(viewLocation);
int[] parentLocation = new int[2];
this.getLocationOnScreen(parentLocation);
int screenX = parentLocation[0] + x;
int screenY = parentLocation[1] + y;
return screenX >= viewLocation[0] && 
       screenX < viewLocation[0] + mScrollView.getWidth() && 
       screenY >= viewLocation[1] && 
       screenY < viewLocation[1] + mScrollView.getHeight();
}

...

//Removed the onInterceptTouchEvent Method

...

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if (!mCanSlide || !mIsSlidingEnabled) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

mDragHelper.processTouchEvent(ev);

final int action = ev.getAction();
boolean wantTouchEvents = false;

switch (action & MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();
        final float dx = x - mInitialMotionX;
        final float dy = y - mInitialMotionY;
        final int slop = mDragHelper.getTouchSlop();
        View dragView = mDragView != null ? mDragView : mSlideableView;

        if (dx * dx + dy * dy < slop * slop && 
            isDragViewUnder((int) x, (int) y) &&
            !isScrollViewUnder((int) x, (int) y)) {
            dragView.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            if (!isExpanded() && !isAnchored()) {
                expandPane(mAnchorPoint);
            } else {
                collapsePane();
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
    return wantTouchEvents;
}

...

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if (mScrollView == null)
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

final float x = ev.getX();
final float y = ev.getY();

if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    mDragHelper.shouldInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

    mInitialMotionX = mPrevMotionX = x;
    mInitialMotionY = mPrevMotionY = y;

    isChildHandlingTouch = false;
} else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
    float dx = x - mPrevMotionX;
    float dy = y - mPrevMotionY;
    mPrevMotionX = x;
    mPrevMotionY = y;

    if (!isScrollViewUnder((int) x, (int) y))
        return this.onTouchEvent(ev);

    if (dy > 0) { // DOWN
        // Is the child less than fully scrolled?
        // Then let the child handle it.
        if (mScrollView.getScrollY() > 0) {
            isChildHandlingTouch = true;
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        if (isChildHandlingTouch) {
            // Send an 'UP' event to the child.
            MotionEvent up = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
            up.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
            super.dispatchTouchEvent(up);
            up.recycle();

            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        }

        isChildHandlingTouch = false;
        return this.onTouchEvent(ev);
    } else if (dy < 0) {
        if (mSlideOffset > 0.0f) {
            isChildHandlingTouch = false;
            return this.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        if (!isChildHandlingTouch) {
            mDragHelper.cancel();
            ev.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        }

        isChildHandlingTouch = true;
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
} else if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) || 
           (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
    if (!isChildHandlingTouch) {
        final float dx = x - mInitialMotionX;
        final float dy = y - mInitialMotionY;
        final int slop = mDragHelper.getTouchSlop();

        if ((mIsUsingDragViewTouchEvents) && 
            (dx * dx + dy * dy < slop * slop))
            return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

        return this.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Again check this for where I'm pulling code.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22720204/172336

Thanks