# Android prevent scrolling property of list view in onScrollListener?

Tags: android, listview, onscrolllistener

I am using [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) in my project. The second panel of `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` only contains the list view of `button` which are scrollable. `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` and scrolling `listview` are working perfectly, but I have to prevent scrolling the `listview` when the `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` is in the `COLLAPSE` state, and scrolling must be active only in the `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` `EXPAND` state. How can I achieve this?

How can I prevent scrolling of the list view in the `onScroll` method of `setOnScrollListener`?

I wrote this but it is not working.

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (slidingLayout != null && slidingLayout.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScrollStateChanged Event *COLLAPSED**********");
            return;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
       if (slidingLayout != null && slidingLayout.getPanelState() == SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScroll Event Event *COLLAPSED**********");
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this can help you :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18367522/android-list-view-inside-a-scroll-view

Comment: try this `listview.setEnabled(false); to disable scrolling

Comment: use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478361/slidinguppanellayout-and-scrollview/22720204#22720204