# Sliding up panel opens completely when sliding starts.

Tags: android

I am using umano sliding up panel and i want the panel to open gradually as i slide up the panel. Is there a way to do this.

Please find the code below.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 app:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
 app:umanoOverlay="true"
 app:umanoDragView="@id/nested_scroll"
 android:id="@+id/slideup_panel"
 app:umanoPanelHeight="300dp"
 app:umanoScrollableView="@id/nested_scroll"
 android:gravity="bottom">

 <View
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:id="@+id/nested_scroll">
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research, do you have windowActionBarOverlay enabled in your style?

```css
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

I've never personally used this library before, so may be wrong, but worth a try

Edit:
Also are you implementing the newest version of the library, because it looks as though there was issues with using a scrolling element within it, caused issues
(reference: [SlidingUpPanelLayout and ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22478361/slidinguppanellayout-and-scrollview))

Comment: I do have windowActionBarOverlay enabled.